# Usage and spelling of "wordlength" and "bitbreadth"

Tags: nouns, word-usage, orthography, compounds, spacing

As far as I know, these are the meanings:

- *wordlength* — for instance, 4 bytes when the bitbreadth is 32 and 8 bytes when the bitbreadth is 64.
- *bitbreadth* — for example, 32 or 64 or 4 bits for a system.

Are these spelled correctly, or should they be "word length" and "bit breadth"? Or perhaps different terms entirely should be used to express these meanings?

Comment: In OED they use a space- word length
Syllabification: (word length)
Definition of word length
noun
Computing
the number of bits in a word.

Answer (score 3):

I think *wordlength* (as a single word, or two words separated by a hyphen or a space) is a bit "geeky" these days. Non-specialists invariably refer to 32- or 64-bit *systems*, and programmers usually refer to 4- or 8-byte [native] *integer* size where the distinction is relevant. But if they were happy with the term itself, I doubt anyone would quibble over which written form you used.

But [bitbreadth](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1900,cd_max:31/12/1985&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22proved%20dough%22&oq=%22proved%20dough%22&gs_l=serp.3...16206769.16210804.1.16211203.12.12.0.0.0.0.113.810.11j1.12.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.8NYmWWlaC-k&pbx=1&biw=1258&bih=865&cad=cbv&sei=aVeWUaXPL6KN0wWBp4HwDg#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22bitbreadth%22&oq=%22bitbreadth%22&gs_l=serp.3...20839.22736.9.23363.2.2.0.0.0.0.44.85.2.2.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.xsHZyD12vbM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=a069d45ad154690d&biw=1258&bih=865) is really a non-starter. That single instance in Google Books is effectively an accidental collocation, and [most instances of the two word forms](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1900,cd_max:31/12/1985&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22proved%20dough%22&oq=%22proved%20dough%22&gs_l=serp.3...16206769.16210804.1.16211203.12.12.0.0.0.0.113.810.11j1.12.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.8NYmWWlaC-k&pbx=1&biw=1258&bih=865&cad=cbv&sei=aVeWUaXPL6KN0wWBp4HwDg#hl=en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22bit%20breadth%22&oq=%22bit%20breadth%22&gs_l=serp.3...879366.879366.10.879736.1.1.0.0.0.0.114.114.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.wp31HOFoXdU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=a069d45ad154690d&biw=1258&bih=865) are actually references to the width of a *drill* bit. [Bit width](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1900,cd_max:31/12/1985&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22proved%20dough%22&oq=%22proved%20dough%22&gs_l=serp.3...16206769.16210804.1.16211203.12.12.0.0.0.0.113.810.11j1.12.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.8NYmWWlaC-k&pbx=1&biw=1258&bih=865&cad=cbv&sei=aVeWUaXPL6KN0wWBp4HwDg#q=%22bit%20width%22&hl=en&tbm=bks&ei=SWmWUeq7EYnb0QXWhIHoCg&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=a069d45ad154690d&biw=1258&bih=865) is more common, but doesn't really suit OP's intended context.

Bear in mind that *word length* normally means *length of a "word"* in computing contexts, which can meaningfully vary. But extrapolation to *length of a [computer] **bit*** is meaningless - what OP means is *width/length of [something] as measured in [computer] bits*.

Even geeks don't normally say things like *"This compiler supports integers of bitwidth X"* (but if they did, they'd use ***bitwidth***, not *bitbreadth*). In practice, they usually follow the same style as non-specialists, and speak of 32- or 64-bit integers, for example.